# How to create inherited class from a class from header in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, header

I'm trying to create simple project to learn header files and inheritance in C++.
I've created header file:

`Bot.h`

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Bot {
public:
    Bot();
    ~Bot();
    bool initialized;
    string getRandomMessage();
    string getName();
protected:
    vector<string> messages;
    string name;
};
```

Then I have `Bot.cpp` where I have

```
/**
 * 
 * @return random message from Bot as string
 */
string Bot::getRandomMessage() {
    int r = static_cast<double> (std::rand()) / RAND_MAX * this->messages.size();
    return messages[r];
}

/**
 * 
 * @return bot's name as string
 */
string Bot::getName() {
    return this->name;
}
```

And now I can't figure out, how to split into header and cpp file and how to handle includes and other stuff to make it all work in my inherited class, that I've implemented like this:

```
/**
 * Specialized bot, that hates everything and everybody.
 */
class GrumpyBot : public Bot {
public:
    GrumpyBot();
};

/**
 * Default constructor for GrumpyBot
 */
GrumpyBot::GrumpyBot() {

    initialized = true;
    this->name = "GrumpyBot";
    messages.push_back("I hate dogs.");
    messages.push_back("I hate cats.");
    messages.push_back("I hate goats.");
    messages.push_back("I hate humans.");
    messages.push_back("I hate you.");
    messages.push_back("I hate school.");
    messages.push_back("I hate love.");
}
```

When I used to have it all in one file, it worked well, but I don't think that this is a good practice and I want to learn this. If anybody could help, I'd be glad.

Comment: what's wrong with your code now? what error are you getting?

Comment: `Bot` needs a `virtual` destructor. And you shouldn't `using namespace std`, *specially* in headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already did it for `Bot` and it is the same with a subclass:

GrumpyBot.h

```
#ifndef GRUMPY_BOT_H //this will prevent multiple includes
#define GRUMPY_BOT_H
  #include "Bot.h"
  class GrumpyBot : public Bot {
  public:
      GrumpyBot();
  };
#endif
```

GrumpyBot.cpp

```
#include "GrumpyBot.h"
GrumpyBot::GrumpyBot() {

    initialized = true;
    this->name = "GrumpyBot";
    messages.push_back("I hate dogs.");
    messages.push_back("I hate cats.");
    messages.push_back("I hate goats.");
    messages.push_back("I hate humans.");
    messages.push_back("I hate you.");
    messages.push_back("I hate school.");
    messages.push_back("I hate love.");
}
```

The `ifndef/define/endif` mechanism is needed in order for the compiler not to include a header a second time when it parses another one that includes it. You have to change your `Bot.h` too, using `HEADER_NAME_H` is just a convention.

Comment: Of course I've tried this, but it keeps me getting this error during compilation `Bot.h:13:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Bot’
Bot.h:13:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Bot’` On ln 12 is the include, on ln 13 is the definition of the class

Comment: Well..now I get diferrent error. `GrumpyBot.cpp:14: undefined reference to `Bot::Bot()'` and the same for the destructor. Wouldn't you mind to edit your post one more time, to show me, how to fix it? I'm quite confused..

Comment: @Dworza You need to implement all of `Bot`'s the member functions. This includes constructors and operators.

Comment: @Dworza juanchopanza is right, but this a different question. Try to do it alone first and ask another question if you still don't understand how inheritance works properly.

Answer (score 3):

Split your classes into separate headers.

Then, you'll have :

Bot.h

```
class Bot{
    //...
};
```

GrumpyBot.h

```
#include "Bot.h"

class GrumpyBot : public Bot{
    //...
};
```

and keep a .cpp file for each class. Then each .cpp includes its corresponding class' header.

On a side note, try to avoid using `using namespace std;` in headers, it's quite not good practice, as it will enable this directive for the whole translation unit the header get in, and it can be dangerous (it could lead to name collision problems).